# Login with facebook using a subdomain

Tags: php, facebook

All,
I'm trying to login with facebook and in my App settings on facebook I have my website. For example the Site URL I have is `http://website.com`. I am actually using subdomains though so I'm not sure how to set this up so that it works with a subdomain. For example my URL that I'm trying to login with is: `http://subdomain1.website.com/sport`. The error message I'm getting from Facebook is:

`Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.`

How can I login with facebook using a subdomain? I obviously don't want to create an app for each subdomain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add website.com in the App Domains field in Basic settings